# Parse Error (Possibly Incorrect Indentation...)

Tags: haskell

When I run this code:

```
test1 :: Int -> String
test1 x = do
    if x == 1
        then "Hello"
```

I get the following error:

```
test-if.hs:4:21: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

I am not sure why this is as I am not using any brackets and I am using 4 spaces as my tabs. Adding brackets doesn't seem to help. What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your `else`?

Comment: In Haskell, an "if" statement must "return" a value along **both** branches - without this property, it doesn't really make sense in a functional sense. The `if ... then ... else ...` expression is what you need, and it does require that `else`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` needs an `else` (what do you want the value to be when `x` isn't 1?).

Furthermore `do` notation is used when working with monads and doesn't make sense in this function.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, I wasn't aware that all branches need an else branch and that I don't need to always use = do when defining a function. Thanks!

Comment: @skacesmith Don't think of them as 'branches'. Haskell's `if a then b else c` is the ternary operator (think `a ? b : c`), not a control flow mechanism (except in the case of using monads).